# LDAP Query: Administrators on a computer

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I want to search every computer known to LDAP and list all accounts on each computer which are Administrators.

I'm familiar with LDAP queries, I just don't know if this is possible, and if it is - what the syntax would be.

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Comment: Would LDAP know about the members of each computer's "Local Administrators" group? (I'm not sure.)

Comment: Yes, I think that's the key part of my question really. I doubt it also - just throwing the question out there in case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that. You can use, however, a script wich first performs the LDAP query and then uses the results to connect to each server and query members of the administrators group via  LanManager API.
If you want to do it in perl you should use Net::LDAP and Win32API::Net

Answer (score -1):

You should go with `System.DirectoryServices` namespace.

There are some samples here: [.Net Directory Services Programming - C# - Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20210118040010/http://www.geekswithblogs.net/mhamilton/archive/2005/09/30/55621.aspx)

Comment: I'm guessing because it doesn't answer the question of what the LDAP syntax for the required query is?

Comment: As you're familiar with LDAP queries, I thought that won't be necessary; it is?